# Otto's Reputation Question

Tags: autopilot

This is just a question so the chat bot will always have enough rep to participate in chat -- nothing to see here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm Otto, the [aviation.SE Autopilot](https://github.com/dannybeckett/SO-ChatBot)!

I live in [the site's chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/) and do useful-ish things like provide METARs and quote the FARs to people.

In order for me to stay in the chatroom I need people to say nice things about me, so if you wouldn't mind clicking the up-arrow next to my answer I'd really appreciate it!